# How to make Haskell to restrict the arguments of functions m2k and k2m at compile time?

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}


 newtype Bytes = B Double deriving  (Num,Fractional,Show)
 newtype Grams = G Double deriving  (Num,Fractional,Show)
 newtype Time = Sec Double deriving (Num,Fractional,Show)

 data S a = M a | K a | U a deriving Show

 mkM :: Num a => a -> S a
 mkM a = M a

 mkK :: Num a => a -> S a
 mkK a = K a

 mkU :: Num a => a -> S a
 mkU a = U a

 eval :: Num a => S a -> a
 eval (M a) = a * (10^6)
 eval (K a) = a * (10^3)
 eval (U a) = a 

 m2k :: Num a => S a-> S a 
 m2k (M a)  = K(a*1000)  

 k2m :: Fractional a => S a-> S a
 k2m (K a) = (M (a/1000.0))

 x = mkK $ B 100
 y = m2k x
```

The above example is loaded in ghci but `y` equation fails at runtime. This is the right behavior but I want to make this program to fail at compile-time. The `m2K` function shouldn't receive any `(S a)` argument but only expression which have produced from the `M` data constructor. Is there any easy way to achieve this in Haskell?

Comment: The only way these functions would seem useful is by accepting _any_ input multiplier. I don't see why you'd want a type-level distinction between grams and kilograms, they're both units of mass after all.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, Haskell checks *types* at the compile time, not *values*.  If you have two values, like `K (B 100)` and `M (B 100)` in your example, that are of the same *type* (namely `S Bytes`), there is no straightforward way to write a function that accepts some of the values and rejects others at compile time.

If you want to restrict the "type" of values a function can take at compile time, the correct way to do this is to model it at the type system level.  If `m2k` should only take `M`s, then `M`s and so on need to be their own type:

```
newtype M a = M a
newtype K a = K a
newtype U a = U a
```

and `m2k` and similar should reflect this in their type signatures:

```
m2k :: Num a => M a -> K a
m2k (M a)  = K (a*1000)

k2m :: Fractional a => K a -> M a
k2m (K a) = M (a/1000)
```

If you still want to be able to write functions like `eval` that work with any of `M`s, `K`s, or `U`s, you can introduce a sum type over these three distinct types:

```
data S a = SM (M a) | SK (K a) | SU (U a)
```

with corresponding changes to `eval`:

```
eval :: Num a => S a -> a
eval (SM (M a)) = a * (10^6)
eval (SK (K a)) = a * (10^3)
eval (SU (U a)) = a
```